# Как можно отфильтровать товары по цене в java

Tags: java, массивы

Как можно отфильтровать товары по цене.
Например есть пару продуктов: морковь - 100р, яблоко - 123р,банан - 122р, треугольник - 101р.
как можно отфильтровать эти продукты по цене, например: сначала недорогие или наобарот.

У меня в голове это выглядет так:
есть 2 массива (в которые можно записывать строковые id). В одном из массивов название товара, а в другом его цена. и у товара и у цены на этот товар одинаковые id (например: название этого товара)
после чего в консоль выводится отфильтрованный список продуктов (просто вывод по порядку, изменять массивы не надо)

Comment: Удобнее было бы использовать Map, у вас как раз название продукта - ключ, цена продукта - значение. С Map все реализуется в несколько строк.

Comment: Использовать компаратор, [как то так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51565461/3129992).

Comment: Charismatic, можно пример?)

Comment: @Charismatic хотел бы я посмотреть как это будет работать для товаров с одинаковой ценой... компараторы однозначно

Comment: ок, но я в душе не чаю что такое компараторы, поможете?

Comment: Зачем использовать массивы? Java - объектно-ориентированный язык, в котором _нужно_ пользоваться классами/объектами или уже можно создавать кортежи (легковесные классы, records).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Массивы, хешированные коллекции, простенькие реализации... Я на это все смотрю и мне это все простеньким вообще не кажется. Нужны продукты - создаем класс, их описывающий, выглядит так:

```
class Product {
    
    private final String name;    
    private final Long cost;

    public Product(String name, Long cost) {
        this.name = name;
        this.cost = cost;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Long getCost() {
        return cost;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Product{" + "name=" + name + ", cost=" + cost + '}';
    }

}
```

Теперь нужен массив из этих продуктов, но лучше колекция, чтобы не заморачиваться с размерами. Осталось затолкать в коллекцию продукты и потом юзать метод сортировки , передавая в него компараторы, описывающие, как именно мы хотим это добро сортировать. Вот и все.

```
class Main{
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        List <Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
        products.add(new Product("морковь", 10000L));
        products.add(new Product("яблоко", 12300L));
        products.add(new Product("банан", 12200L));
        products.add(new Product("треугольник", 10100L));
                
        products.sort(Comparator.comparingLong(Product::getCost));        
        System.out.println(products);        
        products.sort(Comparator.comparingLong(Product::getCost).reversed());
        System.out.println(products);
        
    }
    
}
```

А если у вас вдруг появляются , к примеру, еще и какие-то услуги, у которых тоже есть цена, но там совсем другой класс, их описывающий, то можно легко создать интерфейс с каким-то больным названием в духе Costable и единственным методом Long getCost(), который будет импелементирован и классом продуктов, и классом услуг (и любым другим, имеющим стоимость). После чего наши коллекции/методы можно типизировать не классом продуктов, а интерфейсом с больным названием и заталкивать туда все, что его имплементит (продукты, услуги итд). Еще и полиморфизм поюзаем))

Не изобретайте велосипеды и не ленитесь пользоваться подсказками.
И еще... Деньги всегда считаются только в копейках/центах итд и хранятся в целочисленной (!) переменной и никак иначе!

Comment: Писал свой ответ, отталкиваясь от фразы автора вопроса: "но я в душе не чаю что такое компараторы". Про то, что деньги всегда считаются в наименьшей денежной единице не знал. Учту.

Comment: @SelectionForCollection никто не родился с этим знанием. но раз перед человеком стоит такая задача. то самое время найти ей нормальное решение. а костыли прикручивать люди учаться без труда сами. в этом помощь точно не требуется))

Answer (score 1):

Наверняка есть более изящные способы(как были предложены компараторы, но раз вы с ними не сталкивались, то вот более простая реализация).
Можно использовать массив объектов. Например объявим и реализуем класс Продукт

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Product {

    String name;
    int price;

    public Product(String name, int price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }

    //По таккому же принципу реализуйте нужные вам сортировки
    public static ArrayList<Product> cheaperFirst(ArrayList<Product> products) {
        //Луюая угодная вам сортировка, писал быстро - поэтому то что помню)
        Product buffer;
        for (int j = 0; j < products.size() - 1; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < products.size() - 1; i++) {
                if (products.get(i).getPrice() > products.get(i + 1).getPrice()) {
                    buffer = products.get(i);
                    products.set(i, products.get(i + 1));
                    products.set(i + 1, buffer);
                    i--;
                }
            }
        }
        return products;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Ну давайте наши действия будут происходить в классе Main

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            products.add(new Product("Товар " + i, 1 - i));
        }

        for (Product el: products) {
            System.out.println(el.name + ", " + el.price);
        }

        System.out.println("\n");
        ArrayList<Product> products1 = Product.cheaperFirst(products);

        for (Product el: products1) {
            System.out.println(el.name + ", " + el.price);
        }
    }
}
```

Я убежден, что нам не нужно 2 массива. Мы сравниваем цену и меняем объекты(имя товара привязано к объекту, поэтому оно переедет по списку вместе с ценой).